# Is there as faster way to save the deep memory from oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope

I am somewhat new to oscilloscopes and I need to efficiently extract measurements from an oscilloscope. I have a Keysight 3014T oscilloscope and I have been using its Segmented Smart Memory to capture a sequence of doppler measurements using ultrasound. My issues is that after acquiring the segmented measurements (300 measurements of about 3000 points each), saving them into a USB stick as a CSV file takes about 20 minutes which is not fast enough for the experiments that I am doing. The total saved CSV file is about 58 megabytes which is not THAT big. I am guessing the deep memory of the oscilloscope is contained in some other format within the hardware and transforming it into CSV takes time. Am I guessing right? Is there any other faster way to acquire data from within an oscilloscope?

Comment: Can you transfer it via ethernet in binary format? It is usually faster than CSV

Comment: Can you reduce the sampling rate?  I.e. don't take so many 'points'

Comment: I need the amount of points in order to stay within Nyquist.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [DSOXLAN module](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/product/DSOXLAN/805-lan-vga-module-infiniivision-2000-3000-x-series-oscilloscope.html), you should be able to get these samples rather quickly using the VISA command language, for which there is much tooling - both from keysight themselves as well as for other environments (like Python).

If you don't, well, bad luck, it's not going to get faster than the 12 Mb/s of the full-speed USB port. Since CSV is *always* a bad format for numerical data, and the user manual says (p. 309):

> Acquired waveform data can be saved to a USB storage device in
> comma-separated value (CSV), ASCII XY, and binary (BIN) formats.

Use the binary format. Keysight's tools can read that, but the user manual also documents the file format, so it'd take not much Python/C++/C/Rust/… to get the data from these files.

Comment: Thank you! I used the binary format and it was much faster. Still, I will acquire the module. Cheers!